# NSubstitute mock DbContext that uses private method in constructor

Tags: nsubstitute

I'm just starting with NSubstitute and trying to mock my EF Core database using EntityFrameworkCore.Testing.NSubstitute version 5.0.0.

The issue I'm hitting is that the constructor uses private methods:

```cs
public LampContext(DbContextOptions<LampContext> options) : base(options) {
   ChangeTracker.StateChanged += BeforeSaveModifications;
   ChangeTracker.Tracked += BeforeSaveModifications;
}
```

The `BeforeSaveModifications` is a private static method, so when I try to mock the database like this:

```cs
var context = Create.MockedDbContextFor<LampContext>();
```

I get a null reference exception. If I comment out those two lines, it works fine. What's the proper way to handle this?

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Stack Trace:
> LampContext.g.cs(15,0): at LaMP.API.Models.LampContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options)
> at Castle.Proxies.LampContextProxy..ctor(ICallRouterProvider, IInterceptor[], DbContextOptions`1 options)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
> at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)